# Time attendance SQL statement

Tags: sql

The case check in time between 9:20 to 16:30 and check out its between 21:00 the same day to 3:00 am the next date, this is the table

```
select * 
from checkinout
```

Output:

```
USERID            CHECKTIME
-----------------------------------------
64                2018-03-02 13:04:26.000
64                2018-03-03 01:11:38.000
64                2018-03-03 13:14:01.000
64                2018-03-04 01:44:10.000
64                2018-03-04 13:29:40.000
```

User id 64 check in at 2018-03-02 13:04:26.000 and check out in the next day 2018-03-03 01:11:38.000 and this is what i need to have from the table

```
UserID   checkdate      Checkin         Checkout        workhour
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
64       2018-03-02     13:04:26.000    01:11:38.000    =13:04:26.000-01:11:38.000
64       2018-03-03     13:14:01.000    01:44:10.000    =13:14:01.000-01:44:10.000
```

How can I get this output from the table I have?

Comment: How do you know that the first record is the check in and the second is the check out?

Comment: we have a roll the check  in between 9:14 am to 16:30 and the check out between 21:00 the same day and 3:00 am the next day , so if any one have check between 9:14 am to 16:30  its check in and if check  between 21:00 the same day and 3:00 am its check out

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
select userid,  max(cast(checkin as date)) checkdate, 
max(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),checkin,108)) checkin, max(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),checkout,108)) checkout,
max(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),checkin,108))+'-'+max(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),checkout,108))workhour
from
(select userid, cast(checktime as date) checkdate, checktime,
case when row_number() over(order by cast(checktime as date), checktime) % 2 = 1 
then 'Checkin' 
else 'Checkout' end [Action],
case when row_number() over(order by cast(checktime as date), checktime) % 2 = 1 
then row_number() over(order by cast(checktime as date), checktime)
else row_number() over(order by cast(checktime as date), checktime)-1
end Visit
from #checkinout)a
pivot (min(checktime) for [action] in ([Checkin], [Checkout])) a 
group by userid, visit
```

Comment: its good but if i need to say where checkdate between '2018-03-01' and '2018-03-04' and USERID=64

Comment: Select from the entire statement above in parenthesis and add where clause to filter like this: select from (above statement) a where.....

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you in the ballpark. This uses your added info in your comment about how to identify a Check In Time vs Check Out Time instead of relying on the order of the records when sorted by date.

```
SELECT CheckIn.Userid, 
    Cast(CheckIn.CheckInTime as Date) as CheckDate, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CheckIn.CheckInTime,108) as CheckIn,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CheckOut.CheckOutTime,108) as CheckOut,
    DATEDIFF(hh,CheckIn.CheckInTime, CheckOut.CheckOutTime) as hours
From
    (       
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY checktime) as checkid,
            Checktime as CheckInTime,
            Userid
        From Checkinout
        WHERE CAST(CheckTime as Time) BETWEEN '09:14:00' AND '16:30:00'     
    )CheckIn
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY checktime) as checkid,
            CheckTime as CheckOutTime
            Userid
            WHERE CAST(CheckTime as Time) BETWEEN '21:00:00' AND '24:00:00' 
                OR  CAST(CheckTime as Time) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '03:00:00'
        From Checkinout
    )CheckOut
    ON CheckIn.CheckID = CheckOut.CheckId
```

This is still, potentially, a little sketchy since we are still relying on the order being CheckIn, CheckOut, CheckIn, CheckOut without any deviation, but... again.. ballpark for sure.

Answer (score 0):

here is my approach

sample data

```
--sample data
if object_id('tempdb..#checkinout') is not null drop table #checkinout
CREATE TABLE #checkinout(userid int, checktime DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #checkinout(userid,checktime) VALUES
(64,                '2018-03-02 13:04:26.000'),
(64,              '2018-03-03 01:11:38.000'),
(64,                '2018-03-03 13:14:01.000'),
(64,                '2018-03-04 01:44:10.000'),
(64,                '2018-03-04 13:29:40.000')
```

query below - just replace #checkinout with your table and it should work accordingly.

```
--query, get some sorting in place
if object_id('tempdb..#x') is not null drop table #x
SELECT c.userid,
        c.checktime,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.userid ORDER BY c.checktime) AS 'Sorted'
INTO #x 
FROM #checkinout AS c --replace with your table, and everything should work


--label the rows by checkin or checkout
if object_id('tempdb..#y') is not null drop table #y
SELECT x.*,
       CASE WHEN x.Sorted % 2 <> 0 THEN 'Checkin' ELSE 'Checkout' END  AS 'Type'
INTO #y
FROM #x AS x


--get data into format desired
SELECT cin.userid,
       CAST(cin.checktime AS DATE) AS 'CheckDate',
       CAST(cin.checktime AS TIME) AS 'Checkin',
       CAST(cout.checktime AS TIME) AS 'Checkout',
       DATEDIFF(HOUR, cin.checktime, cout.checktime) AS 'Hours'
FROM #y AS cin
     outer APPLY
     (
        SELECT y.checktime 
        FROM #y AS y
        WHERE y.userid=cin.userid AND y.Type='Checkout' AND y.Sorted=cin.Sorted+1
     ) AS cout
WHERE cin.Type='Checkin' AND cout.checktime IS NOT null
```

output

```
userid  CheckDate   Checkin             Checkout           Hours
64      2018-03-02  13:04:26.0000000    01:11:38.0000000    12
64      2018-03-03  13:14:01.0000000    01:44:10.0000000    12
```

Comment: its good but if i need to say where checkdate between '2018-03-01' and '2018-03-04' and USERID=64